# Is there a reason why some of my Postgres tables don't allow me to enable Auto Indexing on foreign keys?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I'm looking to set up indexing for all of the foreign keys in our production DB to improve efficiency. The foreign keys have already been made, I was worried that I would have to re-create the table with the new indexing on foreign keys but from what I've read that isn't necessary. I have tried adding the foreign keys both through the PGAdmin viewer and by creating individual SQL queries.

When I look at the foreign key settings the "Auto FK Indexing" isn't checked and doesn't let me toggle it.

[image]

So the next thing I tried was deleting the entire foreign key and re-creating it. When I do this it does allow me to toggle the button to enable "Auto FK Indexing" but after I save it and refresh it goes back to the default with Auto Indexing turned off.[image]

Lastly, I tried just adding an index to the FK like this- `CREATE INDEX idx_tablename_ProspectId_2 ON public.table_name ("ProspectId");`

That gave me a success message but again, when I check the ForeignKey it claims that there is nothing there.

Finally, I tried deleting the foreign key and recreating it in SQL like this- `ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.table_name ADD CONSTRAINT "dx_tablename_ProspectId_2" FOREIGN KEY ("ProspectId") REFERENCES public.prospect_info (id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE;`

What seems odd to me is that there aren't any error messages as I add Indexing to the foreign keys. If there are some basic principles that are preventing the foreign keys from accepting the indexing commands, I'd love to learn about them.

Comment: Auto FK Indexing is a functionality from pgAdmin, not PostgreSQL. pgAdmin creates the SQL statements for your indexes when you create a foreign key. Something might be wrong, you could check the source code. https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4

Comment: There is no automatic FK indexing. There is a column, there is the FK you can add to that column and then if you want you can also add an index to the same column. The grayed out Auto FK index indicates that the index has already been created.